# Time Taken By Solr To Fetch From DB

Tags: solr, solrcloud, dataimporthandler, solr6

How to identify the time taken by solr dataimport handler to fetch the results from Database?

Comment: check in the logs...

Comment: 03:12:42,356 INFO  [org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory] (Thread-6606) [core1]  webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=true&commit=true&clean=false&wt=json&command=full-import&entity=coreEntity} status=0 QTime=9{add=[100 (1558521537959559168)],commit=} 0 242988

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti From Logs i get abouve time where Qtime=9{add=[100 (1558521537959559168)],commit=} 0 242988

Comment: 242988ms is the query executing time? Can you please help on this?

Comment: Do you need total time taken or just the time taken for connection and getting the result

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti TIme taken to get connection & getting the result. Also time taken to index the same results